# Random number keeps changing

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a super simple flip the coin game, but it's multiplayer so there is a lot of code in it. In the flipping part of the game, I am having an issue.

I want it so that whenever the coin is flipped, if it lands on heads the number 1 gets stored into the Firebase database, and if it lands on tails I want the number 2 stored.

This is how I have it working right now:

```
private void startGame() {
    flipCoin();
    games.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            HomePage.getCurrentGameID(new HomePage.CallbackID() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String currentGameID) {
                    games.child(currentGameID).child("horT").setValue(getCoinSide());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Once both players join a game and hit 'ready', then this method is called. You can see that first it calls the flipCoin() method which is simply this:

```
private void flipCoin() {
    final Random r = new Random();
    coinSide = r.nextInt(2) + 1;
}
```

And then I am setting the heads or tails (the 1 or 2) in the database using `getCoinSide()` as you can see in this line that I've already posted

```
games.child(currentGameID).child("horT").setValue(getCoinSide());
```

And my getCoinSide() is simply this:

```
private int getCoinSide() {
    return coinSide;
}
```

So this works somewhat. It gets a number and stores it in the database, but the problem is it continuously stores it in the database over and over and over. So the number that defines heads or tails keeps switching every half second to a 1 or a 2. How can I get a static number that has no chance of changing?

Comment: Well, obviously if it the `currentGameID` already has a value set do not set it again, but then there's still issues like race conditions which means you'll need to start a transaction before testing and writing...

Comment: I am confused by your response. currentGameID is not being set here. I have one line of code posted two different times just to single out the important line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written an infinite loop.  You have a listener at a location in the database (`games`) that gets invoked whenever *any value **at** or **under** that location* changes.  Inside your listener, you have some code that writes a value to a location under `games`.  That written value then triggers the listener you added at `games`, which writes another value there, etc.

You're going to have to figure out some other way to meet the requirements of your game without writing a self-triggering listener like this, perhaps by limiting the scope of your listener so that it doesn't also listen to the values it's writing.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize this was looping infinitely. What I did to solve the problem was change `addValueEventListener` to `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` so that it would just get one value and then get out of the method. Thanks again